# TeeChart 3d Pie Thickness

Tags: java, android, teechart

Is it possible to increase pie thickness? Now it is too thin, I want it twice thicker...[image]

Comment: Add links to the library you use

Comment: Teechart, http://www.teechart.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this incrementing the `Chart3DPercent`:

```
tChart1.getAspect().setChart3DPercent(50);
```